# Mock Lerna scoped module with Jest

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, monorepo, lerna

I have a monorepo setup with Lerna. The project is compiled with tsc and the tests are ran with ts-jest v27.

One of the files that I'm trying to test has this code:

```js
import { someFunction } from '@local/package/dist/something'

const someLogic = () => {
  someFunction()
}
```

`@local/package` is a local monorepo package symlinked by Lerna.

I need to mock `someFunction`.

Things I've tried:

---

```js
jest.mock('@local/package/dist/something')
```

Has zero effect, the original file is still called.

---

```js
import * as something from '@local/package/dist/something'

jest.spyOn(something, 'someFunction')
```

Zero effect.

---

```js
import * as something from '@local/package/dist/something'
something.someFunction = jest
      .fn()
      .mockReturnValue(123)
```

Leads to `TypeError: Cannot set property "someFunction" of #<Object> which has only a getter`

---

jest.config.js:

```
{
moduleNameMapper: {
    '(.*)something(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/somethingMock.js',
  }
}
```

Zero effect.

---

I tried to create '**mocks**/@local/package/dist/something.js' next to package.json of the package inside which I have tests.
Zero effect.

---

I'm tired and I need help.... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

These were end to end tests that trigger an HTTP endpoint, the code that I was trying to mock was running in a separate process lol.